# Django admin display only one option in a drop down list created via the use of foreign key depending on the logged in user

Tags: django

Am using django admin dashboard to manage both customers and admin in an online mall. The customers are the owners of the shop while the admin is the one who creates customers and assign shops to them.

**models.py**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
      name = models.ForeignField(Shop)
```

After creating a customer, the admin gives the customers the permissions to add, view, edit, and delete products.

When the customer logs into the same admin dashboard he is able to add, view, edit, and delete products.

The problem is when it comes to selection of a shop to add products to, the customer is able to see other shops hence data leakage.
[image: A picture showing a drop down list created via the use of a foreign key displaying different shops]

Also the customer is able to view products of other shops when the he clicks the products

[image: A picture showing a list of all products in different shops in the mall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `ModelAdmin` you need to override the `get_queryset` and `get_form` methods to only display the shops related to the logged in user. You also need to change the `Shop` model to include a reference to the user.

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Shop(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      owner = models.ForeignKey(User) #add 'on_delete' argument
      # ...

class Product(models.Model):
      shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop) #add 'on_delete' argument
      # ...
```

```
#admin.py
from .models import Shop, Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    
    # ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields["shop"].queryset = Shop.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return form

    def get_queryset(self, request): 
        qs = super().get_queryset(request) 
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(shop__owner=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form you can redefine the queryset used:

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    shops = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Shops.objects.filter(your_filters_here))
```

And same for product